# What is the English equivalent of ストーリー総監修?

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, definitions, terminology

I'm confused as to the meaning of this cinematic term found in the credit of a movie. ストーリー総監修? Story Total Supervising Editor?? I'm not sure what this means. Is there any English equivalent to this or should I just come to my own conclusions?

For context, this credit was given to the author of the original work which the film serves as a sequel to. The credit of 脚本/script was given to another person. I'd just like to understand the English Equivalent of ストーリー総監修 so I can better grasp the role the author played.

Comment: I can't say I'm familiar with this term, but given that google results appear to almost exclusively be for the new Naruto movie, I'm guessing it isn't a particularly common title/position. Perhaps "chief story supervisor"? You might have better results at [movies.se] (or, if your question is about Naruto, [anime.se]). (Also, you probably mean 総監修, not 總監修 - 總 is the pre-simplification form of 総.)

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry for that oversight! You're right, the kanji is all wrong, it should be 総監修. Thank you so much for the correction, or I wouldn't have noticed. I'd rather ask around the Japanese community than the movie go-ers since this term is rather rare though. I've noticed 監修 seems to always be used in the context of editorial supervision...Editor-in-chief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about movies but here is my guess.

“総” means “whole”.
eg. “総収入” is “total income”.

Googling “総監修” gave some examples and it seems to be used as “everything is supervised by *somebody*”.
Thus “ストーリー総監修” seems to mean “the whole story was supervised by *somebody*”.